# reading html file and display in CKEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-parsing, ckeditor

I am currently using CKEditor for my project to read and display the content of a html file.

However, instead of getting the content of the file, all I get is a string: < html > display in the editor.

But if I write the content directly to the page using response.write, then all the content of the file is displayed correctly.

this is the code snippet I used to read the file:

```
    strPathToConvert = Server.MapPath("~/convert/");
    object filetosave = strPathToConvert + "paper.htm";
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filetosave.ToString());
    string content = "";
    while ((content = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if ((content == "") || (content == " "))
        { continue; }
        CKEditor1.Text = content;
        //Response.Write(content);
    }
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?
Many Thanks.

Comment: That should work, do you get any javascript errors or anything?

Comment: No, I dont get any errors, Just the string: <HTML> display in the CKEditor while all the file's content is displayed directly on the page when using response.write. I did lots of searching today but no solution found.

Comment: You may try some experimenting. See what is displayed if you hardcode it to "<html>asfd" or "blablablablalabla". It could be that you need to encode the HTML before setting on the control

Comment: If I change the content of the html file to "<html>asdfas", so I will get the string "<html" to display in less than a second and then disappear. And if "asdfasdfsadf" only, then nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a `while` loop and you are overwriting the contents of CKEditor every time since you use `=` instead of `+=`. Your loops should be:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filetosave.ToString());
string content = "";
while ((content = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if ((content == "") || (content == " "))
    { continue; }
    CKEditor1.Text += content;
    //Response.Write(content);
}
```

a better way would probably be to use

```
string content;
string line;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filetosave.ToString())
{
    while ((line= reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        content += line;
    }
}
CKEditor1.Text = content;
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't even notice that, reading in one line of HTML at a time :-)

Comment: That works great. But I tried your 1st method before, but it did not work. But now it is working.